# Using two nested foreach parallel loops where foreach is part of a function

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

In `R`, I try to run two nested parallel `foreach`loops. The first `foreach` loop is embedded in a function `f` which runs a number of tasks in parallel. The results are combined by a function. The function `f` here is just for illustration; the real function I am working with is more complex, but in the end also returns a scalar or vector.

Subsequently, I need to run `f` many times. `f` runs `x` parallel processes and I want to run `f` again `y` times in parallel. My idea is that this creates a total of `x*y` processes on the machine. However the way I implement these ideas seems not compatible with `foreach` as I get an `unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection` error.

What is the correct way to implement this process?

As a side note: if we use `%do%` for sequential processing in the outer loop, we get the correct result but this computation is not run in parallel.

```
library(doParallel)

# function f contains a random parallel processing task whose results are summed
# if we run f in the global environment we get a result

f = function(x){
  cl2 = makePSOCKcluster(x)
  clusterSetRNGStream(cl2)
  registerDoParallel(cl2)
  r = foreach(j = 1:x, .combine=rbind) %dopar% {
    sample(1:j,1)
  }
  stopCluster(cl2)
  closeAllConnections()
  sum(r)
}

# Now I want to run f y=5 times
# I would expect each of the 5 workers would create x own workers

y=5
cl1 = makePSOCKcluster(y)
clusterSetRNGStream(cl1)
registerDoParallel(cl1)
foreach(j = 1:y, .combine = rbind,
        .export = c('makePSOCKcluster', 
                    'clusterSetRNGStream',
                    'registerDoParallel', 
                    'stopCluster',
                    'closeAllConnections',
                    '%dopar%',
                    'foreach')
) %dopar% { f(j) } # use %do% for sequential processing gives the correct result
stopCluster(cl1)
closeAllConnections()
```

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/nested.html

Comment: @Roland yeah I have seen that one but was not able yet to combine it successfully with the function f. I'll check again.

Comment: You should not manage the cluster within `f`. You should not call a parallelized function within a parallelized loop. The vignette explains why this is not a good idea. Usually, it's best (for performance) to only parellelize the outer loop.

Comment: `closeAllConnections()` in `f()` basically causes the worker to hang up the communication channel with the main R session. So, **never ever call `closeAllConnections()`** -  that can for sure mess up the state of your parallel workers as well as the state of R itself.  It's almost as harsh as calling `quit()`.

Comment: @HenrikB thanks, good point. What should be called instead for closing the workers of the instance?

Comment: `stopCluster()` already does it.  It stops the cluster nodes (=workers) one by one, and when a node is closed the corresponding connection is also closed.

Comment: @tomka, curious, where did you learn to use `closeAllConnections()`?  If it's suggested some widely used document, webpage, blog post, then I think it's worth reaching out to them and asking them to correct this.

Comment: @HenrikB good question. I vaguely remember that I once had a problem with RStudio under Windows not shutting down all workers despite me trying to shut them down with `stopCluster`. They just stayed active. Using `closeAllConnections` was a fix to this problem, but I do not remember where I got the advice. Most probably here on SO. I sort of adapted the 'double shut down' strategy that uses both command lines as a default without reflecting what it may actually do...